# Add css to specific cell in jquery datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jquery and datatables in my project.

What I want now is to add CSS to cell on click of button i.e changing cell color.I only want to change single specific cell value not the entire row

I tried below method and it did not work

```
<table id="food">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Type</th>                         
        </tr>                           
    </thead>    
    <tbody> 
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Apple</td>
            <td>Fruit</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Mango</td>
            <td>Fruit</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Grape</td>
            <td>Fruit</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<button id='button1'>Click me</button>
```

Here is the jquery

```
$('#button1').click(function(){ 

   //Here I want to change row 1,col 3 to red color

    var cell = table.row(1).column(3).node();
    $(cell).addClass('change-color');

 });
```

Thanks

Comment: do you want to change the css for the entire row ? And where is this checkbox ? first column of each row ? Please be describe your situation more in the question

Comment: Hi dhiraj, 

Removed all un necessary things..now question looks simple and clear..

Comment: Can you please provide the HTML of the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this to get cell at column 3 and and row 2 (zero indexed)

```
var nodes = myTable.column(2).nodes();
$(nodes[1]).addClass('change-color);
```

Here is a demo **http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/189Lp6u6/19/**

Answer (score 1):

You can also change all Values defining a columns with an increment i+num

this work with jquery datatables

```
var myTable = $('#example2').DataTable(); 
var columnas = new Array();
    columnas[4] = 4;  
$.each(columnas, function(i, v) {  
   var x = i+3;  
   var nodes = myTable.column([x]).nodes();   
   var y = i+3;   
   $.each(nodes, function(y, v) {  
       $(nodes[y]).addClass('change-color');              
   });
});
```